# EGIT, Github and Eclipse - How to

Tags: eclipse, git, bash, github

I'm working on a game with my team. We're trying to setup github to work with Eclipse. We've downloaded the EGIT plugin and Mylyn, we've created a github (https://github.com/CMNatic/Hello-World)
I've downloaded Git bash and all that, I'm very slowly understanding it.

I'm wondering on how I can code and then publish that to my GitHub folder,
I'm a total 100% noob at this, so please try and be as basic as possible (sorry)

Thanks in Adavance,
CMNatic

Answer (score 1):

If you have your project already created you have to steps to publish it through Eclipse and EGit.

**1. Create your local repo for your project**

- **1.1** - Right click over the project and select Team -> Share Project.
- **1.2** - Select Git as the plugin that you want to use and click over Next.
- **1.3** - Click over "Create..." and create a new repository if you have not created one. -
- **1.4** - Put the name that the repository will have and click over Finish. You can also select the folder where the git repo will be stored.
- **1.5** - Click over Finish.

**2. Push your code remotely**

- **2.1** - Do a commit and push. For that you need to right click over the project -> Team -> Commit
- **2.2** - Put a comment in the commit and select the files that you want to add to the commit.
- **2.3** - Click over "Commit and Push"
- **2.4** - A new window will appear where you can put the settings for the Github repo. You can put the URL (https://github.com/CMNatic/Hello-World) in the URI field, and put your user and password in the other fields. You can store user and password, for that you can select the option "Store in Secure Store". Click "Next".
- **2.5** Select "Source ref" as the master branch and "Destination ref" as the master branch and click over "Add spec". This will asociate your master local branch with the remote local branch of the repo. You can "Force update" if you want to override the current content of the Github repo (be sure that the repo is empty).
- **2.6** Click over finish and you should have your code in Github now.